# Searching database using PDO & PHP, while statement not displaying echo

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am adding a search input and button to my website using PDO, my else statement works and I receive 'no results'. However my while statement seems to have no response. Am I missing anything or have I written something wrong in my code?

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $articles = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE headline = :search");
    $articles->execute(array(':search' => $search));

    if($articles -> rowCount() > 0) {
            while ($rows = $articles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                   $headline = $rows['headline'];
                   echo "headline: $headline<br>";
                  }
    } else{
        echo "No Results";
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I hey the while to execute @Don'tPanic?

Comment: use fetch() instead of fetchAll() and it will work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used the wrong fetch method.

```
while ($rows = $articles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { ...
```

`fetchAll` fetches *all* the rows. So `$rows` is an array of rows, not one row. Consequently the loop will only execute once, and `$rows['headline'];` won't exist.

Just use `fetch` instead of `fetchAll`.

Alternatively, if you still want to use `fetchAll`, you can call it once and then iterate the result with a `foreach` loop.

```
$rows = $articles->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    $headline = $row['headline'];
    echo "headline: $headline<br>";
}
```

Either way should work the same.

---

You should have error reporting set to display warnings and notices on your development server, so PHP can inform you of problems like this. (`$rows['headline']` would generate an undefined index notice.)

Comment: so i need to use ->fetch() ??

Comment: Correctamundo .

Comment: I do not think this is correct because I will need to display all data relevant to what is typed int he search box. I think I may have something wrong in the SELECT statement.? @don't panic

Comment: @DicedMango it will display all the rows that match, because you're calling `fetch` in a loop. It will fetch one row at a time until it's fetched them all.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but this dose not seem to work.

Comment: hold the fire.. This dose work @don't panic! Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am adding 'LIKE' to my select statement.. have I laid this out okay??

 ("SELECT * FROM articles WHERE headline LIKE '%:search%'");

Comment: Don't add the wildcards in your SQL string or the prepared statement won't work properly. Add them to the search term beforehand.

Comment: Like this, for example: `$search = "%$search%"`